# Can anyone help me explaining javascript code for image validation using selenium webdriver?

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, html

I am planning to use a below code to test whether the images on the webpage loaded correctly or not. Can anyone please explain me how exactly this **javascript** code will validate whether the image is loaded or not?

```
ArrayList<WebElement> imgElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[contains(@src,   '.gif')] | //*[contains(@src, '.png')]");

for (WebElement element : imgElements){

boolean imageLoaded = (boolean) ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return  arguments[0].complete && "+ "typeof arguments[0].naturalWidth != \"undefined\" && "+"arguments[0].naturalWidth > 0", element);

if (!imageLoaded)
 {
     System.out.println("Found broken image: "element.getAttribute("src"))
 }
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, as far as I can see `arguments[0]` references an `HTMLImageElement`. That object has a [`complete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement) property which indicates wheter the image is loaded or not. It also has `naturalHeight` and `naturalWidth` properties which together specifies the intrinsic size of the image once loaded. If these properties aren't available, they return 0.

Using what we just learned we can easily see how the following code will determine if the image is loaded or not:

```
return arguments[0].complete 
    && typeof arguments[0].naturalWidth != 'undefined' 
    && arguments[0].naturalWidth > 0;
```

However, there's only the second condition involving checking for `undefined` that doesn't seem to be in line with what MDN says, since `naturalWidth` should be `0` when unavailable, not `undefined`.